# count from different tables with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

table userlogins:

```
userid  logintime
11111   2019.10.10
11111   2019.09.10
22222   2019.10.10
```

table benefits:

```
userid  benefit
11111   A
11111   B
22222   C
22222   C
22222   C
```

I want result as:

```
userid  benefitcount logincount
11111   2            2
22222   3            1
```

This code doesn't work. How can i fix this?

```
select count(B.userid) as benefitcounts, count(UL.userid) as userlogins
from userlogins UL
inner join benefit B on B.userid=UL.userid
group by UL.userid
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you want to get?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Specify the problem and desired outcome. Based on the sample data and the code you've written it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. The code looks good, it will work, meaning wouldn't raise any errors, however not the way you want it

Comment: code is working but not bringing the desired outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` two aggregated subqueries, as follows:

```
SELECT 
    u.userid,
    u.logincount,
    b.benefitcount
FROM
(
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) logincount FROM userlogins GROUP BY userid
) u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) benefitcount FROM benefits GROUP BY userid
) b ON u.userid = b.userid
```

This query can be optimized if you have a unique key in each table:

```
SELECT 
    u.userid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) logincount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) benefitcount
FROM userlogins u
INNER JOIN benefitcount b ON u.userid = b.userid
GROUP BY u.userid
```

Comment: @lewisatep: fixed.

Comment: Thanks.both answers are fine and similar. But can we improve performance?

Comment: @lewisatep: one side question: do you have a unique column in both tables?

Comment: i have unique on benefit but not on userlogin. But i can add new unique column to userlogin when i bring with SSIS